# Clarification about conclusion of $Θ(nlogn)$?

Tags: algorithms, heaps

[image]

1. Why the first part of formula is equal to $2 * 2^2 + ... +  2^{log(n)} = 2^2 + 2^3 +...+  2^{log(n)} = 2^3 +...+  2^{log(n)} =... +2^{log(n)}$
2. What is the logic behind ($2^{log n +1} - 2{log n}$)  ?
3. I don't understand why $2n.log - (2^{log (n+1)} - 2)=Θ(nlogn)$ ? (Please explain what is math logic bihind it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part where the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{\log n}i2^i$, you see that whole summation can be written as that chain of summations (if you sum them all up you'll end up getting the first form on the top). Then you use the summation of power two's formula, i.e. $\sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i= 2^{n+1}-1$.

In the first line $=2+2^2+...+2^{log n}$ the formula is missing a -1 so the result will be $2^{\log n +1}-2$, the second one is missing a 2 so it will be $2^{\log n+1}-2^2$ and so on.

You can write $2^{\log n +1}$ as $2*2^{\log n}$ which is equal to $2*n$. I think what confuses you is that you think they wrote $2^{\log (n+1)}$ where as it is $2^{\log n +1}$.

As for why the $2n*\log n - (2^{\log n +1} -2) \in \Theta(nlogn)$, since $2n\log n \in \Theta(nlogn)$ and $2^{\log n + 1} = 2*n$ thus it is $\Theta(n)$ and from the property of asyptotic notation we can conclude $\Theta(nlogn)-\Theta(n) \in \Theta(nlogn)$.

Comment: thank you so much ...Then you use the summation of power two's formula, i.e. $\sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i= 2^{n+1}-1$ ? what is exactly meaning? and why -1?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990137/the-idea-behind-the-sum-of-powers-of-2) is a better and longer explanation of summation of powers of two. It would be to clumped up to answer that in the same post.

Comment: I have several questions! 1. why $2^{\log n +1}-2$ formula is $2^{\log n +1}$ and why add +1 to power ? 2 .why In the first line -1 is missing? and the formula has -2 and if  -1 is from missing -1 ... what is another -1? (that sum both is -2)

Comment: think of $\log n$ as K, then you can write $2^{K+1}$ and maybe it will be easier for you to make it look like the summation formula. That first line would be the sum of 2's formula but there is no +1 so we can just say it is $(2^{(K+1)}-1)-1$ on the other second line you see it is missing a 2 from the upper one, we wrote the upper one as $(2^{(K+1)}-1)-1$ just subtract -2 from this to get the formula for the second line and so on. Where we said let $K = \log n$ for more readability.

Comment: Why exactly $\Theta(nlogn)-\Theta(n)$ is equal Θ(nlogn) ? can you explain and introduce good source for learning about this! tanks.

Comment: I believe [this](https://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/aysmptotic-notations) would be a good starting place. There are plenty of questions on this forum about that as well.

Comment: According to Θ ... must right part and left part ∈ like Θ(nlogn)−Θ(n)∈Θ(nlogn) have exactly same grow after C(constant ) > (like =2 )!

Comment: Yes for some constant they should have the same growth after a certain $n$.

Comment: But still unclear that why $Θ(nlogn)−Θ(n)$ grow excatlly like Θ(nlogn) because we get Θ(n) after −Θ(n) ! and that is must be O, not Θ  ?! do you understand i mean?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties) is a good explanation. The properties of O notation work for the $\Theta$ as well. When n gets big enough the growth of $nlogn$ will be big enough that subtracting $n$ won't asymptotically affect it that much. General rule is $O(f) + O(g) = O(max\{f,g\})$, works same for $\Theta$ as well.